# Drivers did not reinstall automatically after uninstalling them

Tags: drivers

I am sure you've heard of the old "uninstall a driver and it will reinstall" trick

well, i've uninstalled *multiple* drivers just now and *none* of them have reinstalled by themselves. fortunately, they were all under CD/DVD Drives in device manager, but, holy cow, i dont even know what some of those were. Any help with this one? Windows 10 here. MSI Gaming notebook (model: GL62 6QF). Obviously my disc drive doesn't work now.

Edit: The most logical next step for me here was to turn on automatic driver updates in Advanced System Settings. It was already on. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: First, what problem were you trying to solve originally that led you to this course of action? Second, what devices are you trying to get to work? Have you tried removing/disconnecting the optical drive and then reconnecting it?

Comment: @music2myear It wasn't reading a Doom 3 disc that i was trying to install the game with. I'm just trying to get the disc back to working condition.

Comment: We'd need more information about the current state of your computer to be able to help you. Please add as much detail as you can remember regarding the drivers you removed. Also, can you post a screenshot of your device manager showing any/all devices that appear to be having issues.

Comment: @3D1T0R What kind of information do you need my friend? The CD/DVD section in my device manager is completely gone... Also IDE/ATAPI controllers is missing one which didn't reinstall either.

Comment: Is there a section labeled 'Unknown Devices', 'Other Devices', or something to that effect? Basically I'd like to see anything that shows a little overlay with another icon (like an exclamation point, a yellow 'warning' triangle, a question mark or an arrow) next to / on top of the devices icon. Each icon has a meaning whether it be disabled, not recognized, malfunctioning, etc.

Comment: Usually windows installs missing drivers automatically on restarting. However, if it does not work; You can open device manager and scan for hardware changes OR I would suggest visiting manufacturers website and download drivers from there based on model number of laptop.

Answer (score 2):

There are many products for identifying devices which Windows cannot install.
Below are some free and well-known such products :

- [Driver Booster](https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php)
- [Free Driver Scout](https://www.lifewire.com/free-driver-scout-review-2619196)
- [DriverMax](https://www.drivermax.com/)

For more such products see these articles :

- [10 Free Driver Updater Tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-driver-updater-tools-2619206)
- [5 software that automatically detect drivers and boost your computer](https://windowsreport.com/automatically-detect-drivers-software/)

Warning : Do not let the driver-update program to update any devices for which
Windows has found a functional driver.
Only use it for devices on which Windows has failed.

You may also manually find a driver to a device by using this method :

1. Start Device Manager
2. If you have any device with its driver missing, you will be able to see the device labeled as Unknown Device with a yellow exclamatory sign.
3. Right-click the unknown device and choose Properties
4. navigate to the Details tab and select *Hardware IDs* from the drop-down list
5. Right-click on the top-most value (usually the longest) and choose *Copy*
6. Paste the string into your browser's search engine and choose a driver
   from a reputable driver-database website.

If the copied string looks like
PCI\VEN_**1180**&DEV_**0843**&SUBSYS_382D17AA&REV_05\4&1697FF41&0&34F0,
you may also use
[Device Hunt](https://devicehunt.com/)
to search and identify the device using its Vendor ID and Device Id
(in bold above).

Comment: if any of these work i'll put up the +50 rep right away man. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GL62-6QF#down-driver) is the official drivers download page for your make and model.

Failing that, after installing all the available drivers on the website (need not matter if you already had them installed already just install everything), you must contact the support section and ask them directly what drivers you are still missing and where to get them from.

[Log In](https://register.msi.com/home/login) to your account with them here to ask the manufacturers directly

Extra Useful Info:

[This eBay Link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MSI-GL62-6QF-15-6-034-Laptop-Super-Multi-DVD-Writer-Optical-Drive-GUD0N-/122987191149?_ul=BR&nma=true&si=tmKZmnIhXtXMILdkJ1s4th4NRa8%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) Shows a hi resolution image of the DVD SuperMulti drive extracted from the exact same model of laptop you have. All the manufacturers information is visible when zooming into the photo.

You can find the official drivers for that DVD Drive [Here](http://www.lg.com/us/burners-drives/lg-GUD0N-ultra-slim-dvd-writer). It is the 'GUD0N' drive made my Hitachi-LG.